# Search not filtering min and/or max price properly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a form with multiple search input fields, which min and max values are included. When I try to search all properties which min price is 450 000 I see nothing, but in my database, I have properties that are 2 000 000. 
Also on the same note, If put 1 000 000 as max value It shows me properties that are even 2 000 000.

[image]

Blade template:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'action'=>'AdminPropertyController@search_page']) !!}
    <div class="row flex wrap">

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="search-input">
                {!! Form::text('city_suburb', null, ['class'=>'form-controla', 'placeholder'=>'Search for suburb']) !!}         
            </div>

            <div class="select-boxes none">


{!! Form::select('type', [''=>'Type of property'] + ['apartment'=>'Apartment', 'house'=>'House', 'plot'=>'Plot', 'smallholding'=>'Smallholding', 'commercial'=>'Commercial', 'townhouse'=>'Townhouse'], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}   
                    {!! Form::select('min_price', [''=>'Minimum'] + [450000 => 'R 450 000', 5000000 => 'R 500 000', 1000000 => 'R 1 000 000',2000000 => 'R 2 000 000', 3000000 => 'R 3 000 000', 4000000 => 'R 4 000 000',5000000 => 'R 5 000 000', 6000000 => 'R 6 000 000',
], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}                        
                    {!! Form::select('max_price', [''=>'Maximum'] + [450000 => 'R 450 000', 500000 => 'R 500 000', 1000000 => 'R 1 000 000',2000000 => 'R 2 000 000', 3000000 => 'R 3 000 000', 4000000 => 'R 4 000 000',5000000 => 'R 5 000 000', 6000000 => 'R 6 000 000',
], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}


{!! Form::select('bedrooms', [''=>'Bedroom'] + [2=>'1+', 3=>'2+', 20=>'20+'], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}
                    {!! Form::select('bathrooms', [''=>'bathroom'] + [2=>'1+', 3=>'2+', 20=>'20+'], null, ['class'=>'form-']) !!}
            </div>                                              
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {!! Form::submit('Search', ['class'=>'search bg-brown']) !!}
            <button class="clear-filter button">Clear Filter</button>
        </div>                  
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My search function in the controller:

```
public function search_page(PropertyFilters $filters)
{
   $properties =  Property::filter($filters)->paginate(9);

   return view('pages.search', compact('properties'));

}
```

PropertyFilters.php:

```
public function city_suburb($city){
    if(!$city) {
       return $this->builder;
    } 
    return $this->builder->where('city', $city)->orWhere('suburb', $city);
}

public function type($type){
    if(!$type) {
       return $this->builder;
    } 
    return $this->builder->where('type', $type);
}

public function min_price($price){
    if(!$price) {
       return $this->builder;
    } 
    return $this->builder->where('price', '>=', $price);
}

 public function max_price($price){
    if(!$price) {
       return $this->builder;
    } 
    return $this->builder->where('price', '<=', $price);
}

public function bathrooms($bathrooms){
    if(!$bathrooms) {
       return $this->builder;
    }       
    return $this->builder->where('bathrooms', $bathrooms);
}

public function bedrooms($bedrooms){
    if(!$bedrooms) {
       return $this->builder;
    }       
    return $this->builder->where('bedrooms', $bedrooms);
}
```

QueryFilter.php

```
abstract class QueryFilter
{
    protected $request;
    protected $builder;

    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function apply(Builder $builder){
        $this->builder = $builder;

        foreach($this->filters() as $name => $value){
            if($value && method_exists($this, $name)){
                call_user_func_array([$this, $name], array_filter([$value]));
            }
        }
        return $this->builder;
    }

    public function filters(){
        return $this->request->all();
    }
}
```

All the code below is inside my Property.php

```
protected $fillable = [
];

protected $uploads = '/images/';

public function getFeaturedImageAttribute($path) {
  if ( $path ) {
    return $this->uploads.$path;
  }
}

public function photoPlaceholder(){
    return "https://ibin.co/4C4hfps5SKiw.jpg";
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function photos(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
}

public function offers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}

public function feature(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Feature');
}

public function viewing(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Viewing');
}

public function viewingdate(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Viewingdate');
}

public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilter $filters){
    return $filters->apply($query);
}

public function agent(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Agent');
}
```

Anything possibly done wrong in the logic?

Comment: Can you post your Property model?

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane I edited my question